# Does it make sense to ask this about taking a derivative?

Tags: calculus

If $g(x) = f(h(x))$, does it make sense to ask:  what is $(dg/df)(x)$?

Comment: If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable functions then I suppose one could say $$\frac{df}{dg}:=\lim_{\Delta g(x)\to 0}\frac{\Delta f(x)}{\Delta g(x)}=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{f(x+r)-f(x)}{g(x+r)-g(x)}=\lim_{r\to0}\frac{ \displaystyle \frac{f(x+r)-f(x)}{r}}{ \displaystyle\frac{g(x+r)-g(x)}{r}}=\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}.$$ One cool thing is that $\frac{df}{dg}=\frac{df/dx}{dg/dx}$, which means derivatives behave like ratios. (Edit: just noticed I have $f,g$ switched from the OP, oh well.)

Answer (score -1):

I think it makes sense. But I think that expression also needs to equal $1$ for all $x$ since infinitesimal changes on both sides of the equation produced by an infinitesimal changes in $x$ need to be the same.

Comment: Why do you think different functions need to have the same rate of change?